# Error occured processing XML 'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, error-handling

Can you help me fix this error please? I watch [this videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh) and doing all step by step, after previous video(#9) application worked good. But after [video #10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBMDgbtlNoE&list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh&index=10#t=201.492452) I have some errors. In file aplicationContext.xml when I write this code

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="reader.repository"></jpa:repositories>
```

SpringToolSuite show me error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Error occured processing XML
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;'.
>   See Error Log for more details    applicationContext.xml
>   /RssNews/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF  line 40 Spring Beans Problem.

And when I try to run application on server I see another one error in the console

```
2016-06-01 17:26:24.974:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
2016-06-01 17:26:28.575:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned 1 container path jars, 46 WEB-INF/lib jars, 1 WEB-INF/classes dirs in 3173ms for context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@51abf713{/,file:/F:/Programming/Projects/Java/SpringToolSuite/RssNews/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/F:/Programming/Projects/Java/SpringToolSuite/RssNews/src/main/webapp/}
2016-06-01 17:26:29.210:INFO:/:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2016-06-01 17:26:29.289:INFO:/:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2016-06-01 17:26:29.801:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@51abf713{/,file:/F:/Programming/Projects/Java/SpringToolSuite/RssNews/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/F:/Programming/Projects/Java/SpringToolSuite/RssNews/src/main/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2016-06-01 17:26:29.808:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2016-06-01 17:26:29.954:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@53fcdcfd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-06-01 17:26:29.955:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @9552ms
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>reader</groupId>
    <artifactId>RssNews</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <apache.tiles>3.0.3</apache.tiles>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
            Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
            and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
            TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
            the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="reader">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="reader.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>         

        <jpa:repositories base-package="reader.repository" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven? Or just putting libraries by hand? Can you post the libraries list... it's a dependencies issue, conflicts..

Comment: Yes, I using Maven. Updated my question, you can see libraries list.

Comment: Ok, first thing, try to run a dependency:tree to see if in the reactor you inherit some other Spring version... It's sure that is a dependencies issue.. now we gotta understand which one is giving trouble to you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the latest `spring-data-jpa` on the current moment. It is `1.10.1.RELEASE` but spring versions are a bit outdated in your pom.

Try to update all your spring libraries to `4.2.5 RELEASE` right now.

The reason why you have this you can read at stacktrace

spring-data class `RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser` is trying to execute `getEnvironment()` method which is not placed at `4.0.2` version. So if you're update it to `4.2.5 RELEASE` everything will be fine.

Just a tip: if you have to manage a lot of spring libraries between each other, take a look at **Spring BOM**. It is a feature which will allow you to forget about versioning in Spring.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project->Prefrence->Spring->Validation
un-check all

Comment: could you explain your solution a little bit more?